# Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "lifeTime" of relation "ideas" does not exist laravel после переименования свойства

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel5, миграция, laravel-5.6

Пытаюсь в миграции изменить свойство сущности, используя метод renameColumn()

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private static $ideasTableName = 'ideas';

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table(static::$ideasTableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('period', 'lifeTime');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table(static::$ideasTableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('lifeTime', 'period');
    });
}
```

После выполнения миграции, сущность поменялась, свойство  period изменилось на lifeTime.

Но когда выполняю тесты уже с учетом нового свойства сущности, получаю :

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "Illuminate\Database\QueryException" matches expected exception "App\Services\Package\Exceptions\PackageHasIdeasException". Message was: "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "lifeTime" of relation "ideas" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."instrumentId", "priceFrom", "priceTo", "status", "lifeTime"...
                                                             ^ (SQL: insert into "ideas" ("title", "creationDate", "description", "tradeDirection", "instrumentId", "priceFrom", "priceTo", "status", "lifeTime", "period", "stopLoss", "packageId", "risk", "performance", "likeNumber", "dislikeNumber", "comment", "imageUrl", "resourceId", "isFree", "openAtPrice", "takeProfitReachedId") values (Miss, 1066153944, Et tempora numquam consequatur. Ducimus et sunt ratione vel saepe., 1, 1, 0.3120795, 31.3925883, 0, 172800, 0, , 1, 0, 0, 3, 6, Eum dolor deleniti in hic sunt soluta itaque. Ipsum aut necessitatibus nam a., https://lorempixel.com/640/480/499023, 0, , , ?) returning "id")" at
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:107
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:330
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:333
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:304
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/PostgresProcessor.php:20
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2294
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1285
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:726
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:691
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:554
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:195
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:375
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:196
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:170
/home/user/PhpstormProjects/RaddaR-crypto-back/tests/Integration/Services/Package/PackageServiceTest.php:122
```

Суть задачи в том, что бы поменять имя свойства не потеряв его значения.

Comment: а вы после переименования получили `lifeTime` или `lifetime`? При использовании в двойных кавычках это разные для парсера postgresql вещи. Значение имеет какой именно alter table был сгенерирован.

Comment: @Мелкий на выходе получил lifetime, не заметил этого.
а каким образом мне получить именно lifeTime

Comment: `alter table ideas rename column lifetime to "lifeTime"`